# how to write below mysql query in codeigniter model file

Tags: codeigniter

```
Select SUM(getWorkingday(Dates.DateFrom,Dates.DateTo,'work_days')) as UnpaidLeave 
from (Select convert( case when ( YEAR(`DateFrom`)=paramyear and YEAR(`DateTo`)=paramyear and Month(`DateFrom`)<paramonth and Month(`DateTo`)= paramonth ) then STR_TO_DATE(concat(Year(`DateFrom`),'-',Month(`DateFrom`)+1,'-','01') ,'%Y-%m-%d') Else `DateFrom` end , date) as DateFrom
        , convert( case when ( YEAR(`DateFrom`)=paramyear and YEAR(`DateTo`)=paramyear and Month(`DateFrom`)= paramonth and Month(`DateTo`)>paramonth ) then STR_TO_DATE(concat(Year(`DateTo`),'-',Month(`DateTo`)-1,'-',DAY(LAST_DAY(`DateFrom`))) ,'%Y-%m-%d') Else `DateTo` end , date) as DateTo
    from leaveenjoyed where `EmpId`=paramempid and `LeaveTypeId` in (-1) and (Year(`DateFrom`)= paramyear or Year(`DateTo`)= paramyear) AND (Month(`DateFrom`)= paramonth or Month(`DateTo`)= paramonth)) as Dates
```

Comment: why  do we do your home work? have you look on doucmentation of CI? Have you tried anything?

Comment: [Here's the documentation](https://ellislab.com/codeIgniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this, which is better to your query

```
$this->db->query('Select SUM(getWorkingday(Dates.DateFrom,Dates.DateTo,'work_days')) as UnpaidLeave
from (Select convert( case when ( YEAR(DateFrom)=paramyear and YEAR(DateTo)=paramyear and Month(DateFrom)paramonth ) then STR_TO_DATE(concat(Year(DateTo),'-',Month(DateTo)-1,'-',DAY(LAST_DAY(DateFrom))) ,'%Y-%m-%d') Else DateTo end , date) as DateTo from leaveenjoyed where EmpId=paramempid and LeaveTypeId in (-1) and (Year(DateFrom)= paramyear or Year(DateTo)= paramyear) AND (Month(DateFrom)= paramonth or Month(DateTo)= paramonth)) as Dates
')
```

Comment: use double quotation - ("-query-")

Comment: First Check your query then put into $this->db->query('/* Inside your query*/');